# Unity3d custom Frustum Culling - find all points on the near side of a sphere

Tags: unity, frustum-culling

**Scenario**

I have a custom sphere of 1 million plus vertices that I'm using for an interactive. Looping through 1M+ points per mouse movement is exceedingly costly so I've decided to leverage frustum culling. This helps but all the points on the back-facing side of the sphere are still being looped through which is still very costly.

My plan is to cut the sphere in half with a plane that is perpendicular to the viewing camera's angle. I'll place the sphere origin at the `0,0,0` of the sphere and viola it's cut in half.

**Question**

My issue is that if the plane is at an angle, which it will be 99.9% of the time, how can I verify that a given Vector3 is on the normal side of the plane?

*extra*

- I'm using `GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes` to get the frustum bounds
- While writing this question I thought (and plan) to prototype adding my plane "slice" to the frustum boundary planes then using `GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB` to determine which points should be rendrered

Comment: Presumably you tried [Plane.GetSide(Vector3 point)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.GetSide.html)?

Comment: @DMGregory out of my shame I want to delete this question but perhaps posting my final solution will be helpfull for someone else. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: I'd say a detailed answer is much better than just a link to a relevant function. ☺️ So that sounds to me like a good plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the idea to shorten the camera frustum to end at the center of my target group, check all of my object's collider positions against [`TestPlanesAABB`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB.html), then set the camera frustum back to what it was.

```
public static bool IsColliderVisible(Collider collider, Vector3 targetPos)
{
    UnityEngine.Camera camera = UnityEngine.Camera.main;
    float distanceToCutoff =
        Vector3.Distance(camera.transform.position, targetPos);
    float frustumLength = camera.farClipPlane;
    camera.farClipPlane = distanceToCutoff;
    Plane[] frustumPlanes = GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(camera);
    camera.farClipPlane = frustumLength;

    return GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB(frustumPlanes, collider.bounds);
}
```

*extra*

I may end up using a [nearest-neighbor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbour_algorithm) type algorithm to take a point I know is within view and work form there.